# Применение скобочной нотации в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, объясните простыми словами, что дает скобочная нотация в JavaScript? Почему иногда это лучше, чем прямое присваивание свойству объекта?

Answer (score 2):

Используется когда в название свойства включает недопустимые символы:

```
obj['with space'] = '...'
obj['with-dash'] = '...'
```

Или когда оно еще не определено

```
function setProps(someName) {
  obj[someName] = '...'
  obj2 = {
     [someName]: '...'
  }
}
```

Для создания итераторов

```
const iterator = obj[Symbol.iterator]()
iterator.next()
```